# how to load the dll for System.Management.Automation on runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

using this program as example :

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

class PowershellScript
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string command = "Write-Host 'Hello World'";

        using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powerShell.AddScript(command);
            var results = powerShell.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried different methods to load the dll, but none of them worked

Comment: We need more details. What version of .NET are you targeting, and have you added any packages or assembly references to the project? What errors are you getting?

Comment: You need Net 6.0 or later.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I use NET 8.0, and the errors I get after adding the assembly reference for System.Management.Automation are the following :

Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)